# Why should I go to SHA512withRSA signature for my Android apps?

Tags: hash, android, digital-signature, code-signing, self-signed

I have an Android 11 device and many of my apps and system apps use MD5withRSA or SHA1withRSA as signature algorithm by default.

Why should I take my apps SHA256withRSA or SHA512withRSA? Are there any advantages, if so what are they? **Are there also performance and stability issues?**

Answer (score 4):

One should stop using MD5 and SHA-1 for digital signatures.

MD5's colliding messages can be found in less than a minute and there are online libraries to produce; [corkami](https://github.com/corkami/collisions) and [hashclash](https://github.com/cr-marcstevens/hashclash). Also, SHA-1 is already [shattered](https://shattered.io/), that finding two colliding documents are no longer infeasible, and the attack is faster than the generic collision attack O(2<sup>80</sup>). Even before the attack, it was removed by NIST
s recommendation for the signatures.

Secure signature schemes require the hash of the message and this is first introduced by Rabin; he introduced the hash ( it was then called compression) to prove the security of their signature scheme that we call now the [Rabin Signature Scheme](http://publications.csail.mit.edu/lcs/pubs/pdf/MIT-LCS-TR-212.pdf). Some so-called it, hash-then-sign paradigm, however, it is better not. Since the hashing is part of it.

What is the danger of collisions in the digital signatures is this;

- one can create two colliding messages before the sign, and represent you the document that you wanted, then used the other one in the courts. Some other good examples of hash collision attacks can be seen in [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/87104/18298)

You should use at least SHA256 or SHA512. Apart from the generic collision resistance differences ( SHA256 has 128-bit and SHA512 has 256-bit collision resistance) and output size differences 256 to 512, they have a speed difference due to the fact that SHA256 is designed for 32-bit CPUs and SHA512 is designed for 64-bit CPUs. This can have an impact of around 20% speed difference (tested on 64-bit);

```
openssl  speed -evp sha512 sha256
The 'numbers' are in 1000s of bytes per second processed.
type             16 bytes     64 bytes    256 bytes   1024 bytes   8192 bytes  16384 bytes
sha512           21611.03k    70718.37k   124630.02k   221499.05k   246393.51k   251833.00k
sha256           29623.38k    65545.39k   190875.14k   159992.49k   170860.54k   210594.47k
```

There is another faster one, that is [Blake2b](https://www.blake2.net/) ( another SHA3 finalist that Keccak won), also it has parallel version Blake3, and SHA3 also has parallelhash that can benefit from multiple cores. One can use them if available.

You can use both `SHA256withRSA` and `SHA512withRSA`, the difference is the collision resistance and the target CPU architecture.

512-bit is designed against the quantum attacks that [Brassard et. al](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9705002) exhibited. It has cube-root attack that reduced the collision resistance of any 256-bit hash function to 85-bit security and 512 hash function to ~170-bit. Of course, the other costs are not considered (qbits and preparations). If you are not considering countermeasures against the Quantum attack, a secure hash function with an output 256-bit or more fine for you; choose SHA512 for 64 and SHA256 for 32-bit CPU, or simply choose SHA512 once for all.

---

**note:** Although the [Chosen-Prefix collision](https://www.win.tue.nl/hashclash/SoftIntCodeSign/) attack on MD5 can accept different sized files the [resulting sizes of the files must be the same](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/29672/18298) due to [the length padding of the MD constructions](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/87465/18298).

Answer (score 2):

MD5 and SHA1 are no longer considered secure for cryptographic use due to collision attacks.

It is recommended to use SHA256 or SHA512 instead. Depending on your processor, either of them could be faster (although the difference in performance will barely have a real life impact).

Comment: You may want to mention that SHA-512 is often faster than SHA-256 on 64-bit processors due to its use of 64-bit words, since OP mentioned performance issues (not that they really matter for signatures...)